# Passing parameters to callbacks JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I would like for a callback function to fire after a click event.  Currently I have the JavaScript

```
 $('#btnSubmit').click(function ()
            {
                $('#testDiv').hide('slow', onComplete('test'));
            });


            var onComplete = function (t)
            {
                $('#hiddenDiv').hide();
                alert(t);
            }
```

The callback function is supposed to be fired after the hiding of `#testDiv`.  However, the onComplete function fires first.  If I remove the parameters on onComplete and just give it a reference and not invoke it, then the function fires at the right time, but I can't pass parameters to it.  How can I pass parameters to onComplete and not have it fire before the div is finished hiding?

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/X6tbK/)

Comment: try `$('#testDiv').hide('slow', onComplete);`, passing callback function reference rather than executing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to actually have a anonymous function there wrapping your `onComplete()`:

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
    $('#testDiv').hide('slow', function () {
        onComplete('test')
    });
});
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kXfjG/)

In the jQUery docs:

> **complete**
>   Type: Function()
>   A function to call once the animation is complete.

When adding `onComplete()` without a wrapping function the function will be called immediately, otherwise you need to reference it just with `onComplete`, but then you cannot pass your value unless you use `.bind()` to pass your parameter.

Comment: Can you explain why you have to have that anonymous function to call onComplete and you can't just call onComplete directly?

Comment: @wootscootinboogie Because you can't pass a function reference with attached parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Use anonymous function:

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
   $('#testDiv').hide('slow', function () { 
      onComplete('test') 
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.bind()` :

```
$('#testDiv').hide('slow', onComplete.bind(null, 'test'));
```

The first parameter is the value `this` will have in the `onComplete` function. All other parameters are the argument list.

Comment: Why is the first parameter in bind null and not undefined?

Comment: @wootscootinboogie It doesn't matter what the first parameter is if you dont use `this` in the function `onComplete`.